# Pipe more tails to another program (Logstalgia multiple server)

Tags: bash, pipe

Is it possible to pipe more then one tail result to another program?

I try to use https://code.google.com/p/logstalgia/ and i have X Servers. Logstalgia supports a syntax like:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log | logstalgia --sync
```

for one server it was simple:

```
ssh x.x.x.x tail --follow=name /var/log/apache2/access.log | logstalgia --sync
```

One solution were to write the results of the tails in a temp file and pipe the tempfile to logstalgia. But then i need to delete the tempfile daily cause of the size. Someone ideas?

Comment: Does your connection need to keep running listening new data (I see `tail -f`)?

Comment: Yes. logstalgia shows incoming requests from apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the jobs in background, in a loop, like this:

```
for host in host1 hosts2 andSoOn ; do
    ssh "$host" tail --follow=name /var/log/apache2/access.log &
done | logstalgia --sync
```

Comment: Works! Thank you very much!